# Time and space complexity of string iteration and concatenation in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, big-o

On this question I'm not really concerned so much with the correct answer, but rather, the explanation, since I have seen conflicting answers on the internet for this one.

Here is an example problem:

```
function reverseStr(str) {
  let output = ""

  for (var i = str.length-1; i >= 0; i--;) {
    output += str[i]
  }

  return output


}
```

What is the space and time complexity?

Space Complexity. **My assumption #1 is that space complexity is O(n).** As our input string grows, we will need to store another copy (variable output) of that same size before returning it. However, my confusion is with the fact that strings are immutable, meaning that technically a new copy of a string is made each time we hit a new character in our for-loop and concatenate. Of course, we no longer need our old string, so it will be garbage collected(?)... but is it still stored in memory for some time? Even if it is stored in memory, I don't think it would affect the actual space complexity of this problem, but again, I'm more interested in learning the details here.

Time Complexity. **My assumption #2 is that time complexity here is O(n).** We look at each character once in the loop (that part is clear). Then we perform a concatenation. However, my assumption is that the cancatenation of `'a' + 'bcd'` takes the same time as the concatenation of `'a' + 'bcdefghijklmn'` ... or does this direct concatenation linearly take more time as the two strings increase in size? If that is the case then the time complexity would be O(n**2)...

Thank you very much.

Comment: For space complexity, it probably depends on JavaScript implementation. Strings are immutable, but that doesn't mean that there isn't some in place optimization the browser does to create a string buffer / byte instead of multiple string objects. The answer to question two is similar, but also depends on the complexity of C's (or however the browser does it) memcpy.

Comment: since browsers are implemented in c++ and the language supports mutable strings, I think both time and space complexity are O(n). But I will follow this thread to see if anyone has a better answer.